# Which geometric shape of icosahedron origin has 180 faces 270 edges 92 vertices?

Tags: geometry, terminology, polyhedra

Essentially, I am trying to find the specific name of the **convex polyhedron or icosahedron shape** in the gif below. The 3d software (*Blender*) reports 92 vertices, 180 faces and 540 edges, although there are 270 unique edges. Every face is a triangle, composite surface patterns include a number of **hexagons** and **pentagons**.

The convex shape is of [`icosahedron 3v` origin](http://geo-dome.co.uk/article.asp?uname=domefreq), as the pentagon *frequency* (or edge quantity from one pentagon to another) is 3 edges (see link). However, the frequency (and `3v`) naming scheme seems to be non-standard.

The [`snub dodecahedron`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snub_dodecahedron) matches the *convex shape specified* (see gif below) very closely, **except** that the regular pentagons (within the *snub dodecahedron*) have a central vertex, thus increased vertices, edges and triangle faces.

The [`pentakis dodecahedron`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentakis_dodecahedron) matches the `icosahedron 2v`. The `icosahedron` is the 1v variant. Perhaps there's a pattern in naming convention I'm missing to help discover the name of the *shape* in question.

[image: "dome" model I am attempting to identify]

Comment: Who said this thing should have a name in the first place? Besides, 540 can't be true, as $92-540+180\ne2$.

Comment: @IvanNeretin See my answer. 540 edges is the sum of the edge counts of each face, which is therefore twice the number of actual edges.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solid is topologically equivalent to the polyhedron obtained by performing a kis operation on a truncated icosahedron – adding a shallow pyramid on each original face. As such, it is a **kis-truncated icosahedron**.

It is also a [geodesic polyhedron](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic_polyhedron), formed by subdividing each icosahedral face into nine triangles at frequency $3$, and in Wenninger's notation described at the Wikipedia link is $\{3,5+\}_{3,0}$.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Parcly Taxel - that identity has helped me recreate the model. For posterity, it can be created using `antiprism` software with the command: `geodesic -c 1 -f 3 ico | antiview` to produce the same model.